# Calculating the area under a fit

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, so I'm sorry if the questions is trivial.
I have a fitobject, created using 
`fit1 = fit(x, y, 'smoothingspline')`.

Now I want to calculate the area under the fit.
How can I achieve that? The fit seems to behave in a different way than stand curves.

I tried `trapz(fit1)`, but it failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/integrate.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `fitobject` you need to use the actually interpolated data, which requires some changes in your code:

```
% example data
x = (0:1:10)';
y = 10*x-x.^2;

% reduced step size
x2 = (0:0.001:10)';

%interpolated data by using 'spline'
y2 = interp1(x,y,x2,'spline');

%calculation of data as suggested
A = trapz(x2,y2);
```